# JWT gives invalid token

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jwt

Working locally, my jwt token is invalid but in jwt.io it shows verified signature. Not sure what i am missing. I am having invalid signature whenever i tried to make a call to a api whithin  the app.

Link.js

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const Link = require("../models/Link");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth.middleware");
const router = Router();

router.get("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
const links = await Link.find({ owner: req.user.userId });
res.json(links);
} catch (error) {
res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong, try again" });
}
});
```

auth.middleware.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("config");


module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
return next();
}

try {
const token = req.headers.authorization; // Token

if (!token) {
  return res.status(401).json({ message: "No Authorization" });
}

const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("secret"));

req.user = decoded;
next();
} catch (error) {
res.status(401).json({ message: "No Authorization" });
}
};
```

Links.tsx

```
const LinksPage: React.FC = () => {
const [links, setLinks] = useState([]);
const fetchLinks = useCallback(async () => {
try {
  const fetched = await request("http://localhost:5000/api/link/", "GET", null, {
    Authorization: Token,
  });
  setLinks(fetched);
} catch (error) {
  alert(error);
}
}, []);
};
```

Comment: Are you using it as a Bearer token? If so, make sure you strip any unnecessary characters from the token string before you verify.

Comment: How is the token created? And what is the exact error message?

Comment: It's difficult to help, if you don't respomd to comments and answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had to json.parse(token) which stored in the client in order to jwt.verify(token, secret), but instead i was verifying string that contains object of token and userId.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "**req.headers.authorization**" was not what you looking for.
Try to **console.log(req.headers.authorization)** F12 in chrome, firefox.

I suggest you also **POSTMAN** (free software). It help me a lot for debugging the back end (server side).